# Slow down SKSpriteNode with Impulse

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, skspritenode

I have a simple game, where after my score the ball gets more speed with

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 1, dy: -1))
```

So now i want to slow down after he loses. I tried:

```
ball.pause = 0
```

and many other codes, that i found on the web. Can you help me?

// Sorry if this is not a advanced Question, I'm not that long in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the ball completely, you can run this line:

```
ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

This sets the velocity to nothing, effectively stopping the ball, without pausing it.

If you only want to slow it down, you can try doing something like this:

```
ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: ball.physicsBody.velocity.dx - 5, dy: ball.physicsBody.velocity.dy + 5)
```

This brings the velocity closer to nothing (designed for your example), rather than completely stopping it.

Alternatively, you could apply an impulse in the opposite direction, that would slow down its movement in the original direction:

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -1, dy: 1))
```

Note that if you're trying to completely pause the ball (not just slow down or stop it, but pause it's actions) you would run this: `ball.isPaused = true`

Comment: thanks, but if i want to do this : ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -1, dy: 1)) .  The Ball doesn't bounce anymore from the walls out.

Comment: @user6083214 What do you mean by that. All it does is apply an impulse in the opposite direction, which should slow down its movement